# Скины в Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Кто сталкивался с необходимостью или, возможно, из чистого интереса пытался организовать смену пользовательского интерфейса? Прошу советов, литературу, исходники...

Знаю, что есть спец. компоненты, но они платные.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Бесплатная библиотека [тут](http://www.alphaskins.com/index_rus.php). Описание там же 
Работал с этими компонентами на 7 и на XE. Удобно и просто в использовании.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, самое простое и проверенное решение.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве варианта можно использовать компонент TImage как плацдарм для размещения картинки-скина. Настроим прозрачность формы. После чего логично было бы отключить видимость формы и привязка события перемещения за клиентскую область окна. В этом случае мы получаем нестандартную форму с изображением, которую можно перетаскивать и на которой можно размещать другие компоненты формы.